# How do I get screen to both source bash and start in the working directory?

Tags: bash, osx-mavericks, gnu-screen

I'm on OSX Mavericks and having trouble with gnuscreen both sourcing bash and starting in the working directory at the same time. Solutions that I've seen for the former clash with the latter.

Comment: What the heck do you mean by "sourcing bash"?  It  *is* bash, and it's always going to source your `~/.bashrc`.  Do you mean you want it to run your `~/.bash_profile` as well?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want it to do. I have env vars there that I'd like to retrieve.

Comment: `cd working_dir; screen bash -l` will move to `working_dir` and start a login shell of `bash` inside `screen`.  Because it is a login shell, it will source `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: That last command does the trick, but it also means that I can't just type in `screen`, but have to do `screen bash -l`. I suppose I can alias it, but how can I make it so that screen always does that?

Comment: @user592419 I solve the problem differently.  My `~/.bashrc` tests to see if my shell variables are defined.  If they aren't, it defines them.  (These definitions are shared with `~/.bash_profile`.)

Comment: Ok, so that seems to work where I put all of my env vars in ~/.bashrc, don't use ~/.bash_profile, and get rid of `shell -bash` in ~/.screenrc. If I even have bash_profile though, then osx seems to take that as precedent and doesn't load the vars. Thanks John.

Answer (score 0):

Put something like this in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PROFILE_RUN=1
```

And then put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -z "$PROFILE_RUN" ]; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, then something else is going on in your case. Please provide more details of your configuration if you want to explore this path.